# Apache Spark error, Cloned Python environment not found

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am attempting to upgrade huggingface to a later version of what we currently have, 2.11. when i install any newer version of the transformer via pip install transformers=={any version}in azure databricks notebook, I receive the following error during execution. I am pretty new to this, but any feedback on ways to troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cloned Python environment not found at /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-89bc8046-d7ae-4968-b280-fc233a9bf3e4
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.waitForPythonEnvironment(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:313)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:844)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:844)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$getOrCompute$1(RDD.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1376)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1303)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1367)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:367)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:320)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:642)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:645)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: have you used `%sh pip install` or `%pip install` ?

Comment: used %pip install, the package appears to have installed successfully, doing a pip list afterwards shows that the version of the transformer has been updated to the version specified in the install.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below **steps to install huggingface library on azure databricks**

**Step1:** First use install transformers using this command - `pip install transformers`

[image]

**Step2:**  To test installation try this - `from transformers import pipeline`

[image]

**Step3:** Next install pytorch with this command - `pip install transformers[torch]`

[image]

**Step4:** To install Tensorflow use - `pip install transformers[tf-cpu]`

[image]

**Step5:** To test installation I used `print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('we love you'))`

[image]

This way I successfully installed huggingface library.

**Refer** - [Installation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/installation.html)

Comment: Thank you will give this a try

Comment: hmm, looks like it installed successfully, but the databricks jobs are timing out now and getting the error mentioned above, Cloned Python environment not found, i have isolated to it being related to updating the transformer library

Comment: For timeout jobs refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69116120/16036480