# Jar job timeout limits at databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Is there any Jar job timeout limits or Jar job can run without limits at databricks ? Our application starting long running spark job for a weeks, creating spark sessions and "fire" subjobs, but in August release notes I found that notebooks limiting job execution for 2 days. Is it possible to run streaming jobs with such limits ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` to 100000 and `spark.network.timeout` to 200000 in **spark-defaults.conf** file.

Code -

```
.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "100000 ") \ 
.set("spark.network.timeout", "200000 ")
```